# how to print external id of a group in odoo 8?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I would like to print external id (XML ID) of a group in command line so I have written following code

```
    group_employee = self.pool['ir.model.data'].get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'base', 'group_user')[1]

    all_usr_group=self.pool.get('res.groups').search(cr,uid,[])
    all_usr_group2=self.pool.get('res.groups').browse(cr,uid,[group_employee])


    print "\n\nUsername\t-----\tGroup-----\tExternalID\n"
    for j in all_usr_group2:
        for x in all_usr_group2.users:
            print '\n\n',x.name,"\t",j.name,'\t',j.id,'\n\n'
```

But the above code only prints username, respected group name and ID of that group. I want to print its external id. Any help??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing the external id in the print statement, and therefore it does not print it.

ir_model_data should hold the external id.

try this link [here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/showing-external-id-on-forms-56089) as it explains how to get it.

Hope this helps.